# TWebBrowser & OpenLayers 3

Tags: delphi, openlayers-3, twebbrowser

I'm trying to use OpenLayers in a TWebBrowser in Delphi.

When I open a simple example from their site using OpenLayers v4.3.1, I don't seem to be able to pan the map.

WebBrowser1.Navigate( 'http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html' );

I've set the embedded webbrowser mode by using code found in another post.  setEmbeddedWebbrowserMode( iemIE10 );

OpenLayers v3.4 seems to work, however.  I'm able to use the following fine:
WebBrowser1.Navigate( 'http://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter01_01_basic_map.html' );

I'd like to be able to use the most recent API if possible.  Any idea why the new one isn't working in TWebBrowser?

Comment: There is no such thing as XE10.

Comment: Rather than us try to recreate what you are doing, it would help if there was a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your help and quick response David!  There really is only one line of code to get this to work.  It should just be loading an HTML page with a simple openlayers map.  I tried re-wording my original question as well.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: It's the attempts to avoid compat mode that matter really.

Comment: got it!  I tried two methods, the first was embedding the metadata into the page.  Without it, it didn't load at all and get the js error with the open layer api.  Secondly, I also added an entry to the registry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION REG_QWORD 0x00002711 (10001)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the examples is that they contain document mode meta tag for the [**EdgeHTML**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx) mode:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

and they do not work properly with IE11 web browser control (we faced a few problems with mouse input as well). Advice here is simple, serve a proven copy of OpenLayers library to your clients and before they get full compatibility with IE11, try to use IE10 mode in your web application:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

or use another embedded web browser control (e.g. CEF based).

Comment: I made a copy of the page and hosted it on our server without the meta tag and everything worked!!  thank you very much for your help!!